# What are the differences between two different type of excel data source in ssis

Tags: ssis

What is the difference between oledb provider for EXCEL in oledb data source and excel data source in data flow task of ssis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are essentially the same thing. The Excel data source uses the Microsoft OLE DB Jet 4.0 provider to connect to the Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

compatibility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280527(SQL.100).aspx